# QML: Problems with ScrollView interactive

Tags: qt, qml, scrollview, interactive

I have problems with my QML ScrollViews in a Qt application. I can not avoid the interactive mode, even setting the property to 'false'

For testing, I have the docu QML example loaded in a QQuickView:

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QtQuickControlsApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickView* pView = new QQuickView();
    pView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/TestScroll.qml"));
    pView->setColor("white");
    pView->setHeight(400);
    pView->setWidth(600);
    pView->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

TestScroll.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ScrollView {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ScrollBar.vertical.interactive: false // Not working

    ListView {
        model: 20
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            text: "Item " + index
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How is the  `QtQuickControlsApplication`  `#define`d in your code .. ?  in other words .. if you replace it with `QtGuiApplication` , do you still get the issue ?

Comment: Using QGuiApplication instead of QtQuickControlsApplication I have the same problem...

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible with `QGuiApplication` ..  disabling interactive scrollbar works with your code.

Comment: I'm afraid I am reproducing this issue with QGuiApplication... I am using Qt 5.9.6, with Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Then good idea to try another version .. could be a bug ? i used 5.13.1 , with MSVC2017

Comment: I have also installed Qt 5.12.3, I have tried now but it still fails... at least for me...

Answer (score 0):

I think I did not explain my problem properly, sorry...

What I need is to avoid the 'bounce' at the end of the scroll view when scrolling using the wheel. When I use the scrollBar for scrolling, I get no bounce at the end of the scrolling screen

Thanks,
Diego